# Errors with simple declaration file in TS for JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, typescript, react-tsx

I'm trying to copy what was done in this link [here](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc) while making a slight modification. Instead of using daterangepicker, I'm using [react-list-nav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-list-nav). However, I still am unable to get my project to "notice" any of the listnav functions, such as $('#demoOne').listnav();

My copy of typings.d.ts is below

```
interface JQuery {
   "react-list-nav"(options?: any, callback?: Function) : any;
}
```

In my index.ts I am importing as follows:

```
import * as rln from "react-list-nav"
// this errors
// $('#demoOne').listnav()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want this in your `typings.d.ts`

```
declare interface JQuery {
  listnav(options?: any, callback?: any): any
}
```

Comment: I've done this. However, I am still getting the error that it can't find the declaration file for module "react-list-nav" when I try to import.

Comment: Include `declare module "react-list-nav";` in your `typings.d.ts` to resolve your import error.

Comment: Ok, there is no longer an import error so thank you for that. however, I am now getting an issue in my console saying ".listnav is not a function".

Do you know what I'm missing?